# Dropbox API: HTTP status 400 {"error": "v1_retired"}

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a file to Dropbox using their API. I have already followed the complete tutorial, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

When I execute it, I am facing the following error message along with `HTTP 400 - Bad Request`:

```
{"error": "v1_retired"}
```

My composer.json file is as follows:
[image: Composer.json]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error message because version 1 of the Dropbox API is no longer available, as stated on the GitHub repository of the library you used. The tutorial you were using was probably outdated.

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php

```
"Do not use this SDK. It relies on Dropbox API v1, which is obsolete."
```

The README advises you to use any of the provided community libraries which can be found at [this page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/communitysdks).

Comment: thnx for your reply https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk i used this one but not able to understand the flow ..... can you plz guide me
i only want to upload file